# how to make Xilinx design suite 14.6 EDK work with board ML501 for 12.3

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am a total newbie on xilinx, FPGA, VDHL etc.
So please kindly guide me through this problem of mine.

I have installed xilinx 14.6 in 30 days evaluation license.

In one of my lectures I need to use ML501. 
So I copy the professor's `Xilinx_Legacy_ML501` folder (with full licence) to my 14.6 board folder.

When I run EDK, the ML501 doesn't show up.
How do I make my EDK from Xilinx version 14.6 read the ML501 for 12.3?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Xilinx is no longer supporting those boards, you have to install the board support for them  in your XPS environment.

Check out [AR35623](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/35623.htm) that describes the necessary steps to set up and get XPS to work with boards such as ML501!

> Create a directory structure similar to the following:
>
> C:\ < Global_Repository > \ < Library_Name > \boards
>
> 1. Download the [zip file](http://www.xilinx.com/Attachment/Xilinx_Legacy_Boards.zip) containing the ISE software 11.5 boards which are now "Legacy Boards"and unzip itto the newly created boards
>      directory.
> 2. Set the Global Repository setting in XPS through the Edit > Preferences > Application and fill in your Global Repository directory
>      name in the Global Repository Search Path data entry field.
> 3. Restart XPS running Base System Builder. The now old board file will be available for BSB.

Hope this helps.